# Table in latex compressed vertically in multicolumn document

Tags: tables, acm

I have been trying to put a table in a multicolumn document. But it's being compressed vertically. Not sure what i am doing wrong...
[image]

Below is the code I have to put the table:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|| p{1cm} | c | c ||} 
\hline
Question & Explanation \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
1 & ... \\
2 & ... \\
3 & ... \\
4 & ... \\
5 & ... \\
6 & ... \\ [1ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Table Showing the Questions for Visualisations with their 
Explanations}
\label{table:questions}
\end{table}
```

Please note that the "..." in the code are actually long sentences.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: don't scale tables `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{` otherwise you get bad results, as you show.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! cause of you problem is use of `\resizebox`. to prove this suspiction, pleas extend your code sniped to small but complete document with your table. with your code snippet is not possible to reproduce your proble,. btw, you define three columns but use only two ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use column types that allow line-breaking for columns 2 and 3. I suggest you load the `tabularx` package and use (suitably modified versions of the) `X` column type. Oh, and don't use `\resizebox` -- it's virtually guaranteed *not* to deliver what you're trying to obtain.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,lipsum}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}lLL@{}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Question} & Explanation \\ 
\midrule
1 & \dots & \dots  \\
2 & \dots & \dots  \\
3 & \dots & \dots  \\
4 & \dots & \dots  \\
5 & \dots & \dots  \\
6 & \dots & \dots  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table Showing the Questions for 
   Visualisations with their Explanations}
\label{table:questions}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-8] % some paragraphs of filler text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `c` columns  which force the text on one long line, and then scaling the entire table to use an unreadably small font (never use `\resizebbox` with tables). Instead specify reasonable column widths to allow line breaking within the cells. Also don't use `[h!]` usually latex warns and changes it to `[ht]` but including `p` makes it more likely that the table can be positioned.

so replace

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|| p{1cm} | c | c ||}
```

by

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|| p{1cm} | p{4cm} | p{6cm} ||} % or whatever widths you need
```

Comment: from table code sniped i see that op from three defined columns use only two :-) and he use two column document so table had to narrower than column width. actually this is not clear so i asked op to provide mwe ...